# flutter pub get failed(1; So, because flutter_app depends on url_launcher ^5.7.7, version solving failed.)

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart, dart-pub

-Error message

```
The current Flutter SDK version is 1.20.3.
Because url_launcher >=5.7.7 <6.0.0-nullsafety depends on url_launcher_platform_interface >=1.0.9 <2.0.0-nullsaf


Because url_launcher >=5.7.7 <6.0.0-nullsafety depends on url_launcher_platform_interface >=1.0.9 <2.0.0-nullsaf
ety which requires Flutter SDK version >=1.22.0 <2.0.0, url_launcher >=5.7.7 <6.0.0-nullsafety is forbidden.
So, because flutter_app depends on url_launcher ^5.7.7, version solving failed.
Running "flutter pub get" in flutter_app...
pub get failed (1; So, because flutter_app depends on url_launcher ^5.7.7, version solving failed.)
```

-pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  fl_chart: ^0.12.0
  url_launcher: ^5.7.7
```

I can't get pub...
How can I solve this problem??
Thank you for reading and I'll wait for your advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try following.

-pubspec.yaml

```
version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.7.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  fl_chart: ^0.12.0
  url_launcher: ^6.0.0-nullsafety
```

Comment: after upgrade flutter, it worked! but thank you for your answer :)

Comment: upgrading url_launcher to version 6.0.0 solved my issue. thanks!